# question on minimal polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3+3x-1$ and let $\beta$ be a root of $x^3-x+2$. Find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2+\beta$.

My attempt to solution was this: i found a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, satisfied by $\alpha^2$, namely this: $x^3+6x^2+9x-1$. Then i have a finite set of generators for $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha^2,\beta]$, which is: $1,\beta,\beta^2,\alpha^2,\alpha^2\cdot\beta,\alpha^2\cdot\beta^2,\alpha^4,\alpha^4\cdot\beta$ and $\alpha^4\cdot\beta^2$. Then i multiply $\alpha^2+\beta$ (whose minimal polynomial i'm looking for) times each of generators, and i express the results in terms of generators. Now i got a 9x9 matrix whose characteristic polynomial is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients satisfied by $\alpha^2+\beta$. If this is correct, i'm left to prove that this is actually the minimal, but i don't know how, maybe with considerations on finite extensions generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Do you know some way which requires less computation?

Comment: Over which ring do you consider these polynomials? $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: @m_l yes of course

Comment: I don't think there is a general, less computation intensive method of obtaining minimal polynomials of algebraic numbers. Rough guideline for the rest of the proof, I'm in a bit of a rush: Think of the endomorphism (of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space) induced by multiplication with $\alpha^2+\beta$. The matrix you describe represents this endomorphism with respect to your chosen basis, so the matrix's minimal polynomial is the one you're looking for. Over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ this is easy to prove, it shouldn't be much harder over domains. (No zero divisors!)